# Angularjs - My view doesn't add template when data entred

Tags: angularjs

This is my angular code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('userController', ['$scope', 'dataFactory', function ($scope, dataFactory) {

    $scope.User;
    getUsers();
    function getUsers() {
        dataFactory.getUsers().then(function (response) {
            $scope.Users = response.data;
            $scope.userStyle = {
                "width": response.data.length*265+'px'
            }
        })
    }

    $scope.insertUser = function () {
        var user = {
            Name: $scope.Name,
            Username: $scope.Username,
            Password: $scope.Password
            ImageUrl=$scope.ImageUrl
        };
        dataFactory.insertUser(user)
            .then(function (response) {
            $scope.status = 'Inserted User! Refreshing User list.';
            $scope.Users.push(user);
            }, function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to insert User: ' + error.message;
            });
            getUsers();
        };
    }]);


myApp.factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    dataFactory.getUsers = function () {
        return $http.get('/Home/GetAllUsers');
    }
    dataFactory.insertUser = function (user) {
        return $http.post("/Home/InsertUser", user);
    };
    return dataFactory;
}]);
```

and this is my template

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="frame" ng-controller="userController">
    <ul class="project-list" ng-style="userStyle">
        <li ng-repeat="u in Users">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                <span class="image">
                    <img src="{{u.ImageUrl}}" alt="" />
                </span>
                <span class="title">{{u.Name}}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

when add a user, the user added successfully but template doesn't rendere it dynamically and when i print Users

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{Users}}</label>
</div>
```

It's correctly and dynamically updated and added the user, or put it into a table correctly and add it, But for rendering template must refresh the browser
What is my mistake??

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with asynchronous calls in Javascript. You are making a call to your server to post the data. But as soon as the call is made you are also calling `getUsers()`. By the time you call `getUsers()` data will not be inserted in to the table and the database still returns the original list of the users.

The solution is to call `getUsers()` only after the http post call is successful, which means you should call it in the first call back of `.then` like below:

```
$scope.insertUser = function () {
        //Fake customer data
        var user = {
            Name: $scope.Name,
            Username: $scope.Username,
            Password: $scope.Password
            ImageUrl=$scope.ImageUrl
        };
        dataFactory.insertUser(user)
            .then(function (response) {
            $scope.status = 'Inserted User! Refreshing User list.';
            $scope.Users.push(user);
            getUsers();
            }, function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to insert User: ' + error.message;
            });
        };
```

If you have got everything else correct, this should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
As I told befor When new User Added I print the User string (json) and it updated dynamically
But my template that shows users doesn't add new user Template

Comment: I try your solution but unfortunately it doesn't work.
I want add new user template without refreshing my browser

Comment: Can you clarify **want to add new template**

Comment: All of my users are shown in an ul li List.
I want when a new user is added to the list, Shows there whithout refreshing browser.
with this code new user add to the ul li list after refreshing

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
***((using two controller binding))***
wrong:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="frame" ng-controller="userController">
  <ul class="project-list" ng-style="userStyle">
    <li ng-repeat="u in Users">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span class="image">
                    <img src="{{u.ImageUrl}}" alt="" />
                </span>
        <span class="title">{{u.Name}}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div ng-controller="userController">
  <form ng-model="user">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Name">Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Name" name="Name" ng-model="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Password">Password</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Password" name="Password" ng-model="Password" />
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update" ng-click="insertUser(user)" />
  </form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>{{Users}}</label>
    <br />
    <label>{{userStyle}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

and Correct:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="frame" ng-controller="userController">
  <ul class="project-list" ng-style="userStyle">
    <li ng-repeat="u in Users">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span class="image">
                    <img src="{{u.ImageUrl}}" alt="" />
                </span>
        <span class="title">{{u.Name}}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <form ng-model="user">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Name">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Name" name="Name" ng-model="Name" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Password" name="Password" ng-model="Password" />
      </div>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Update" ng-click="insertUser(user)" />
    </form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>{{Users}}</label>
      <br />
      <label>{{userStyle}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you Saurabh Tiwari for your answers

Comment: Can you explain briefly what was the root cause of your issue and how did u tackle it. This helps any other user in understanding any similar issue

Comment: Of course.
I had a form that insert my new users and I used ng-controller to refer it to my angular controller,
And  I had a Html template to show my registered users and I refer ng-controller again to my angular controller in it, so when a new user entred just one of them(my form) has been updated and my Html template do nothing when new user has been entered

Comment: the solution is just put the ng-controller in body tag ;-)